# How to set content after editor initialization in ng2-lazy-trumbowyg editor ? Angular 2/4

Tags: angular

not able to set data in ng2-lazy-trumbowyg editor. after initialization. please help.

Need to add text tuner content in editor on click text tuner content list

Plunker link here : plnkr.co/edit/J8l5rbW2lWp796QAuUyW?p=preview

Comment: First ty for providing an plunker but could you specify your problem ? For me everything seems to work.

Comment: hi @Doomenik, Updated plunker please check. https://plnkr.co/edit/J8l5rbW2lWp796QAuUyW?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

https://plnkr.co/edit/V2nL73TqLQLmpDugRRXj?p=preview

If you read the official [documentation](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/documentation.html#manage-content) you can find more about it.

The module includes all trumbwyg js files so you can achieve it with jquery easily:

```
onTtcClick(event, ttc){
      $('.trumbowyg-editor').trumbowyg('html', ttc);
      //this.content = ttc;
      alert(ttc);
  }
```

Comment: yes, we can do with jQuery but, i was looking in angular way. BTW Thanks. :)

Comment: I´m sorry to say it, but inside of the component are just some predefined Jquery functions. For content changing there is nothing. As an Example the saved content is done like this: this.savedContent.emit(this.trumbowygEl.trumbowyg('html')); Same function, its only predefined in a component.